# Needed a jquery plugin for vertical menubar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menubar

I am tired of searching for a jquery plugin for a vertical menu bar which appears like [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Rx2p-ApprRM/UJ6r9lsl57I/AAAAAAAACZg/1Aayt2tWYgo/s320/website+menu+2.png), but the text being rotated 90 degree something like the third text in [this](http://sciblogs.co.nz/code-for-life/files/2010/05/rotated_text.jpg) image. Can anyone help me out. Thanks in adv.

Comment: you could code this yourself instead of using a plugin?

Comment: Nope. I must be using jquery. !

Comment: code it using jquery then?

Comment: Because i am not good enough to code using jquery.!

Comment: Wait a "jquery" is a thing now?

Comment: @Jared: Well i really dunno. Like i said i am new to it. Do we call it a jquery plugin or a jquery itself i m not sure. But all i know is i can get a menubar using jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Srikaantha I was making a joke, don't mind me. :) Generally people call them "plugins".

Comment: @jared: Thanks for the info. Lemme edit the question once again.!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 transforms to rotate an element 90 degrees if you *really* want it.

I'm not aware of any jQuery plugins or any other scripts that can achieve this. All JavaScript can do is make it easier for you to change CSS properties very quickly (it does no animating by itself).

Answer (score 0):

i found this way.

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mCQyE/